# C# Mongo Query In not returning result

Tags: c#, mongodb

I'm having issue with getting back a result when using the Mongo In query. When I've tested the same query in native mongo, it's bringing back the correct result. Im trying to bring back all the ids that match in the temp array.

```
     var temp = new BsonValue [collection.Count()];
     for (int i = 0; i < collection.Count(); i++)
     {
        temp[i] = collection[i].ID;
     }

     var query = Query.In("ID", temp);
     var collection2 = db.GetCollection<TXT>("TXT").Find(query).ToList();
```

Comment: I don't know what the function Query.In(string, Array<T>) does. can you give me a link about that one?

Comment: http://api.mongodb.org/csharp/current/html/M_MongoDB_Driver_Builders_Query_In.htm   I don't know if this helps

Comment: so, you are looking if the value "ITEMID" exists in collection "temp" which was filled with ITEMID values (therefore, i suppose non of them were the "ITEMID" sting).

Comment: I ran the same ids in MongoVue and got the results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of MongoDb's C# driver are you using? It looks like you might be using a deprecated version of the driver.

Here is an example of how we use to use the .In filter in version 2.0.1.27:

```
var filter = Builders<INVENTTXT>.Filter.In(item => item.ITEMID, temp);

var result = await db.GetCollection<INVENTTXT>("INVENTTXT")
                     .Find(filter)
                     .ToListAsync()
                     .Result;
```

In the legacy driver, assuming that your INVENTTXT looks something like this:

```
class INVENTTXT
{
    [BsonId]
    public ObjectId _id { get; set; }
    public String ITEMID { get; set; }
}
```

Then this works for me to pull the values back:

```
public static void GetWhereIn()
    {
        var collection = new List<INVENTTXT>()
        {
            new INVENTTXT {ITEMID = "52719635"}
        };

        var temp = new BsonValue[collection.Count()];
        for (int i = 0; i < collection.Count(); i++)
        {
            temp[i] = collection[i].ITEMID;
        }

        var query = Query.In("ITEMID", collection.Select(c => BsonValue.Create(c.ITEMID)));
        var collection2 = db.GetCollection<INVENTTXT>("INVENTTXT").Find(query).ToList();

        var count = collection2.Count;
    }
```

Comment: 1.9.1 driver is being used

Comment: When you initialize the temp array, does it help if you add items like this: `temp[i] = BsonValue.Create(collection[i].ITEMID);`

Comment: It helps get the item ids to pull. Is there another way?

Comment: What do you mean it gets the item ids to pull? You could also do something like: `var query = Query.In("ITEMID", collection.Select(c => BsonValue.Create(c.ITEMID)).ToArray());`. Did adding the BsonValue.Create get the items to pull back properly from the mongo collection?

Comment: That still didn't work for me. I'm going to investigate more but I find it crazy that when I run native query against mongo it works correctly.

Comment: What is the actual type of the ITEMID field?

Comment: Its a string. So I just hardcoded a bson array with the ids and it worked but the code doesn't ??

Comment: Can you update your code to show what you did that worked? I just spun up a local mongo instance and tried `var query = Query.In("ITEMID", collection.Select(c => BsonValue.Create(c.ITEMID)));    var collection2 = db.GetCollection<INVENTTXT>("INVENTTXT").Find(query).ToList();` and it worked. Is ITEMID also the BsonId for the document?

Comment: `text` var temp = new BsonValue []{"52719635"};
              // var query = Query.In("ITEMID", collection.Select(c=>BsonValue.Create(c.ITEMID)).ToArray());
               var query = Query.In("ITEMID", temp);
               var collection2 = db.GetCollection<INVENTTXT>("INVENTTXT").Find(query).ToList();

Comment: I updated my answer with the code I got it to work with. I suspect it not working has something to do with the BsonId. Also, to make a code block in a comment, you use the `  key

Comment: `var temp = new BsonValue []{"52719635"};`  I passed this in directly into the Query.In

Comment: Do you get an exception or is just nothing returned when you don't pass in the faked out temp array?

Comment: Did you see my edited answer? I literally did the exact same thing on my computer and it worked (Retrieved only 52719635 despite there being multiple records in the mongo db)

Comment: I did. Still no luck. I'm thinking about just using the query builder to create a dynamic OR. This has been a such a headache.

Comment: I figured out what it was. The values I was putting back had a space on the end. I love data entry people. Anyway, thank you for your help and enjoy the plus 1.